# decision making process

Tags: visas, uk, application-status

I have applied in Munich, Germany to have a tourist visa to visit UK.
Usually, from experience, how long does it take to have the decision made?
I have tracked my visa through TLS.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

According to the statistics published by the UKVI service (which you can find [here](https://visa-processingtimes.homeoffice.gov.uk/y/munich-germany/visits-visas/general-visit-6-months-or-less)) 99% of tourist visas handled through Munich in August 2018 were decided in 15 days, with 100% being decided within 30 days.

Note that these are actual figures for actual visa applications. Some visas take longer than others so this is not a guarantee that your application will necessarily be decided as quickly.